# CSS - How to align divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

so i got this list of divs 200 by 200 but they display vertically
now i pretty much want my whole site to be horizontal driven like the metro ui

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

div {
    display: inline;
    background-color:black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 2px yellow;
}
```

if i apply display: inline, they all shrink??? why
DO: uncomment display: inline; in jsfiddle css and see

http://jsfiddle.net/uVY5V/3/

whats a good way to lay everything horizontal or inline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving `white-space: nowrap` to the body tag and `display: inline-block` to the div tag does the trick.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVY5V/8/)

Comment: now can i set a limit of horizontal width so divs jump to the second row @Mr_Green thanks

Comment: @GunrJesra I am not sure whether you are allowed to change html. but adding `<br>` tag in between the div's can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements cannot have a set width or height.

Block elements cannot be side-by-side (`float` is cheating :p)

`display:inline-block` is the best of both worlds ;)

Comment: but my whole site should scroll horizontally if exceeded in elements,, any idea on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `text-align: justify` for the `div.wrapper`, and you can use the `display:inline-block` for the div list. Like this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="search_tile" class="search_tile"></div>
    <div id="timeline_tile" class="timeline_tile">  </div>
    <div id="conversations_tile" class="conversations_tile"></div>
    <div id="source_tile" class="source_tile"></div>
    <div id="11_tile" class="demo_11_tile"></div>
    <div id="14_tile" class="demo_14_tile"></div>
    <div id="12_tile" class="demo_12_tile"></div>
    <div id="13_tile" class="demo_13_tile"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body{
background-color: blue;
}
.wrapper {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  word-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper div{  
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom:1;
    background-color:black; 
    width: 200px; 
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: solid 2px yellow;
    -webkit-transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out, height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out, height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out, height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out, height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out, height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper .placeholder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  background:none;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/ArnIg). If you are interested, you can click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) and [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/text-align-justify-and-rwd.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you want.
This will make them go horizontally until the end of the width.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuGPU/)

HTML:

```
<div id="search_tile" class="search_tile"></div>
<div id="timeline_tile" class="timeline_tile"></div>
<div id="conversations_tile" class="conversations_tile"></div>
<div id="source_tile" class="source_tile"></div>
<div id="11_tile" class="demo_11_tile"></div>
<div id="14_tile" class="demo_14_tile"></div>
<div id="12_tile" class="demo_12_tile"></div>
<div id="13_tile" class="demo_13_tile"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-color: blue;
width:100%;
}

div{  
    /*display: inline;*/
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: solid 2px yellow;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We’ve been using floats for layout pretty much since we left tables behind. It’s a quirky solution that can often cause troubles, but if you know what you’re doing, it works.

One interesting alternative to floats that people are turning to more and more lately is to set the display value of an element to inline-block.

```
div{  
        display: inline-block;
        background-color:black; 
        width: 200px; 
        height: 200px; 
        margin: 10px; 
        padding: 5px; 
        border: solid 2px yellow;

    }
```

Comment: but my whole site should scroll horizontally if exceeded in elements,, any idea on that?

Comment: In jsfiddle the OUTPUT tab width is limited.you can use width auto and overflow:auto to get scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this a few different ways:

1. Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uVY5V/4/)
2. Add `float: left;` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uVY5V/5/)
3. Leave everything as-is and add some content to your divs as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uVY5V/7/)

Comment: this is not making everything scroll horizontally either, like my whole site should not scroll vertaclly, only horizontal, thats great now i can display them horizontally but they still follow the line-by-line rule??